# Combine the css of two adjacent siblings

Tags: css

Is there a way to to combine the css of two adjacent siblings? I have some code generated by some wordpress theme where I'd like to use css to modify.

For the code below, I would like to hide the p "hide-me" when the class "myclass" also was given a class name "john"

would like to have something like this:
(.first-sibling .myclass.john)  ~ (.second-sibling .hide-me) {display:none;}

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="first-sibling">
    <p class="myclass john">Paragrah to determine the hiding of hide-me</p>    
  </div>

 <div class="second-sibling">
   <p class="hide-me">Hide this if myclass has a class named "john" </p>  
 </div>
```

Thank you

Comment: I think you would need JavaScript for that.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you are asking for with your current HTML you need to use Javascript.  Your other option is if you can apply class john to the parrent then you can have CSS such as this and it would work:

```
.first-sibling.john + .second-sibling{
  display: none;
}
```

Here is a JS Fiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/exk0ex8c/1/

You can also further manipulate HTML so that the two p elements are under same div and then further use CSS Selectors to accomplish this.  For list of all CSS selectors you can view here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: Thanks. I can't do that because the html is generated by the theme.

Comment: @Pandora then what you ask for is currently not possible with CSS3, from what I've read online this was a suggestion made for CSS4, using $ prefix.  Maybe you can do more research on that.  What I am talking about is allowing to select a parent.  Then you can just select parrent of John and then the sibling like I did above.

Comment: @Pandora usually premium themes will let you add custom scripts and CSS.

Comment: @Pandora I am not talking about Wordpress Themes, I am talking about CSS  Selectors.

Comment: Thanks all for your guidance.